# SlidingTabLayout not displaying on output

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 and trying to implement tabs for one of my activities. I have added all the code but don't seem to be getting any output on the phone. I do not need ActionBar, just SlidingTabLayout, but it doesn't show anything other than a blank screen when I run.

Iphone6Activity.java

```
package com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Iphone6Activity extends Activity {



private ViewPager mPager;

private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iphone6);

    //Sets font for text
    //Typeface vodaLt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "VODAFONELT.TTF");
    //TextView vodaHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
   // vodaHeading.setTypeface(vodaLt);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ip6pager);

    //mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.ip6tabs);

    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);


}




class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    String[] tabs;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment=MyFragment.getInstance(position);
        return myFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tabs[position];
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private TextView textView;
    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position){
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }


    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup     container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container,     false);
        textView= (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            textView.setText("The page selected is "+bundle.getInt("position"));
        }

        return layout;
    }
}

}
```

activity_iphone6.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/iphone6"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore.Iphone6Activity"
android:background="#ffffffff">


<com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/ip6tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/ip6pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using MyPagerAdapter class. Uncomment out this line to set an adapter for your ViewPager:

```
//mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: I've done so and get the following error: Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager'

Comment: change to "this.getSupportFragmentManager()"

Comment: tried that, receiving the same error 'Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager''

Comment: Keep that line the same, but in your class definition, change it to "public class Iphone6Activity extends FragmentActivity"

Comment: that fixes the error, however when I run the app and try to open the Iphone6Activity, it shows the error 'Unfortunately, Vodafone Store has stopped.' Also, on the Design view in Android Studio, it is still showing as blank, there aren't any tabs showing up.

Comment: What is Vodafone Store? Is that related to your app at all?

Comment: Yes, that is the name of my application.

Comment: So.. what's the stacktrace you get in logcat?

Comment: 07-01 20:24:42.134    4580-4580/com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore, PID: 4580
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.hashmi.omar.vodafonestore.Iphone6Activity$MyFragment.onCreateView(Iphone6Activity.java:103)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
 and there are more errors

Comment: Just did some research on the error, turns out that 
    if(bundle!=null)
        {
            textView.setText("The page selected is "+bundle.getInt("position"));
        } 
was the problem